# Form input field with lazy model cleared after changing unrelated property in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do somple functionality in vue.js.

I need input field with lazy model, so it is updated only when `onchange` event of the input field is triggered (`msg` in this example).
But I also need some interactive field which changes asynchronously (`other` field in this example).

Problem is, that when I update the `other` field. The input with `msg` model resets to previous state, so it is very hard to change `msg`.

Is there a way how to overcome this issue?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#vm',
 data: {
  msg: '',
  other: 0
 }
})

setInterval(function(){
 vm.other = vm.other + 1
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vm">
 <input type="text" v-model.lazy="msg">
 <div>{{ msg }}</div>
 <div>{{ other }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For text inputs, `change` happens when a field is altered, and loses focus.  If you simply type in the input and don't blur, the change hasn't happened.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, it is the reason why I'm using `v-model.lazy`. I'm not interested in partial updates. Just try the code snippet to see the problem (type something in the input field).

Comment: I'm saying that is your issue.  You type in your input, but do not blur, so your `msg` is unchanged in the model.  You then alter your model `other` variable, causing the view to redraw.  And your input value is overlayed because it's value does not match the value of `msg` in the model.

Comment: ok, so if I change one unrelated part of the model, all fields in the view are rerendered, not just the changed part?